# Sort 2 times mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have query like this:

```
.find({conversationId: conversation})
                .sort({'createDate': -1})
                .skip(perPage * page)
                .limit(perPage)
```

It will return 5 last records, but that 5 records will be sorted wrongly, how can I sort them again in opposite direction?

Comment: What do you mean by sorted wrongly? you mean ascending not descending? or sorting by diff column? or what?

Answer (score 1):

```
.find({conversationId: conversation})
            .sort({'createDate': -1})
            .skip(perPage * page)
            .limit(perPage)
            .sort({'createDate': 1})
```